# Можно ли упростить код?

Tags: python

Код достаточно простой, заменяет последнюю букву в слове на "у". Но при этом занимает аж 2 строчки и смотрится не красиво. Можно ли его упростить до 1 строчки?

```
number_of_lines = len(team)
result = team[:number_of_lines-1]+"у"
```

Comment: `team[:-1]` и всё

Answer (score 0):

```
team = 'привет'
result = team[:-1] + 'д' # result = f'{team[:-1]}д'
print(result)

привед
```